# virtualenv AssertionError with Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, virtualenv

I am using RHEL 6.3 and have 2.6.6. I need to use the Python 2.7.6. I compiled python from source, installed pip and virtual env.

Now I am trying in different ways:

```
virtualenv-2.7 testvirtualenv
virtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7 myenv
```

However I am getting AssertionError. Full trace:

```
    New python executable in testvirtualenv/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in testvirtualenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...
  Complete output from command /tmp/testvirtualenv/bin/python2.7 -c "import sys, pip; pip...ll\"] + sys.argv[1:])" setuptools pip:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/pip-1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/log.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 2696, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 429, in __init__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 443, in add_entry
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 1722, in find_in_zip
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 1298, in has_metadata
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 1614, in _has
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources.py", line 1488, in _zipinfo_name
AssertionError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/PKG-INFO is not a subpath of /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv_support/setuptools-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv-2.7", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.11', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv-2.7')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 820, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 988, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 956, in install_wheel
    'PIP_NO_INDEX': '1'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.11-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 898, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /tmp/testvirtualenv/bin/python2.7 -c "import sys, pip; pip...ll\"] + sys.argv[1:])" setuptools pip failed with error code 1
```

Comment: To clarify, you received the same assertion error despite trying in two different commands, `virtualenv-2.7 testvirtualenv` and `virtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7 myenv`, right?

Comment: Hi Dave, yes same error for two cases

Comment: Have you tried running the python you've built?  For example, are you able to run it, and then do something basic like `import os;`?  I ask because it looks as though virtualenv has a test to verify your python install by copying it to tmp and running `import sys, pip;`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What I found and how I solve it:

There is an issue with the virtualenv 1.11 version:
https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/issue/129/assertionerror-egg-info-pkg-info-is-not-a

My solution:

Start again the installation specifying an older version of virtualenv. (1.10.1 is ok)

```
/usr/local/bin/easy_install-2.7 virtualenv==1.10.1
```

Then you can proceed with the rest of the installation:

```
virtualenv-2.7 testvirtualenv
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the virtualenv  version to 1.10.1 works for me in a RHEL 5.8

```
yum groupinstall "Development tools"
yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tk-devel wget
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tgz
tar -xf Python-2.7.6.tgz 
cd Python-2.7.6
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make && make altinstall
cd ..
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.7.3.zip  --no-check-certificate
unzip distribute-0.7.3.zip
cd distribute-0.7.3
python2.7 setup.py install
cd ..
easy_install-2.7 virtualenv==1.10.1
virtualenv-2.7 --distribute project
source project/bin/activate
python -V
Python 2.7.6
deactivate
python -V
Python 2.4.3
```